# Add a new property and return a value that depends on other properties Db First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to add a new property and return a value that depends on other properties

```
public class Item
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string? ItemName { get; set; }
        public int ItemPrice { get; set; }
        public int ItemTax { get; set; }
        public string? Descrption { get; set; }

        public int TotalPrice   // I WANT TO ADD THIS
        {
            get { return ItemPrice * ItemTax; }
            set { }
        }

    }
```

so when I added a **TotalPrice**  and I want it depends on **ItemPrice** & **ItemTax**

The problem is after add migration and update database the column is added but when I insert a new record in the table the **TotalPrice**  is not affected by **ItemPrice** & **ItemTax**

the migration add this

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
                name: "TotalPrice",
                table: "Items",
                type: "int",
                nullable: false,
                defaultValue: 0);
        }
```

is that applicable to add property like this on DbFirst

```
 public int TotalPrice  
        {
            get { return ItemPrice * ItemTax; }
            set { }
        }
```

Comment: I don't think db context migration will automatically account for something like this. this looks like a job for db triggers

Comment: Its much better to do it from your DTO, in the database just store ItemPrice and ItemTax

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Store computed property with Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58116856/store-computed-property-with-entity-framework-core)

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with database context migrations. You need to introduce a backing field. In your above example your model will end up looking something like this:

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ItemPrice { get; set; }
    public int ItemTax { get; set; }
    public int _totalPrice;
    public int TotalPrice 
    {
        get { return ItemPrice * ItemTax; }
        set { _totalPrice = value; }
    }
}
```

If you're using version 3.0+ of EF Core you'll need to tell EF to use the computed property rather than the backing field:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
       .Entity<Item>()
       .Property(e => e.TotalPrice)
       .UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Property);
}
```

Test Result:

```
public string Test()
{
    Item item = new Item();
    item.ItemPrice = 10;
    item.ItemTax = 10;
    _context.Item.Add(item);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return "Success";
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm using EF CORE 6 and the backing field doesn't work with me but after I'm using HasComputedColumnSql("[ItemTax ] * [ItemPrice ]"). it works with me

Comment: Yes, using `HasComputedColumnSql("[ItemTax ] * [ItemPrice ]` is the most direct calculation method, but it will limit the calculation of multiple tables.

Comment: so what should to use in case of multiple tables?